# Local IP Address is not reachable after installing a third party VPN?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, ip

I have ASP.NET website and SQL Server working fine by using my local ip address `192.168.1.123` but yesterday I have installed a VPN client after this I was unable to navigate my websites using `192.168.1.123` and connect my SQL database using the IP. My IP is still same checked through ipconfig.

Ipconfig output,

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\aa>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 16:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f071:e6f2:13a1:151%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.123
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{635F5060-B721-4F84-8610-DA10C2A93210}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 14:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Reusable ISATAP Interface {468E327D-B0E3-4119-B115-1035F41B6BAE}:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{8BBEAD36-4CE6-4311-88AB-1B04C099810B}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:2c8a:384a:3f57:fe88
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c8a:384a:3f57:fe88%24
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C28FCB0D-EA0A-4B10-B3A1-686F734CFAAD}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{0100A585-8C83-4961-8230-0846C9214D4C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{02AF8393-241F-4B4B-85B1-BCA2F139F4B5}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: Installing the client should not give you problems. Connecting to VPN is another story. Need more details and your ipconfig output.

Comment: @jake see my edit

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious. Is the web server turned on?

Comment: Is the web server on your local machine (the same machine the VPN is on)?

Comment: Yes and yes. Means web-server turned on and on same machine

Comment: Check your ports, there is a chance FOR SOME REASON that the VPN is grabbing ports that the web server/sql server is using, making them unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your routing table using, for example, `netstat -nr`.

I'm not sure how your VPN client would handle a clash/overlap between your local and remote network addresses, but this might be a possibility you should exclude